# Does Presto support Parquet format?

Tags: presto

Running CDH4 cluster with Impala, I created parquet table and after [adding](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/impala-user/y00_u1riil4) parquet jar files to hive, I can query the table using hive.

Added same set of jars to /opt/presto/lib and restarted coordinator and workers.

```
parquet-avro-1.2.4.jar
parquet-cascading-1.2.4.jar
parquet-column-1.2.4.jar
parquet-common-1.2.4.jar
parquet-encoding-1.2.4.jar
parquet-format-1.0.0.jar
parquet-generator-1.2.4.jar
parquet-hadoop-1.2.4.jar
parquet-hive-1.2.4.jar
parquet-pig-1.2.4.jar
parquet-scrooge-1.2.4.jar
parquet-test-hadoop2-1.2.4.jar
parquet-thrift-1.2.4.jar
```

Still getting this error when running parquet select query from Presto:

```
> select * from test_pq limit 2;
Query 20131116_144258_00002_d3sbt failed : org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
```

Comment: Not yet, I'm Ukrainian, we have revolution here, will do later

Comment: Did you test his solution?

Answer (score 2):

Presto now supports Parquet automatically.

Comment: Hi. I can't find how to read parquet.

Would you please answer [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669728/how-to-read-parquet-files-using-facebook-presto)?

Comment: that means if we `create table with (partioned_by = 'date')`, automatically the created table will be stored as Parquet? Could you elaborate by pointing to relevant documentation?

Comment: To create the table in Parquet format, you'll need to add `WITH (format = 'PARQUET')`. There's an example of that (for ORC) here: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#examples

Comment: You can also set the Hive configuration property `hive.storage-format=PARQUET` to have tables default to Parquet format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the jars in presto **plugin dir** instead of presto **lib dir**.

Presto auto loads jars from plugins dirs.